# Moving URL - telling Bing Webmaster Tools

Tags: 301-redirect, bing, bing-webmaster-tools

We're moving a site, we've set up 301's from the old pages to the new ones and told Google about the move, but I couldn't find any were to tell Bing. Is there a feature to do this in Bing Webmaster Tools?

Comment: Bing will update its results automatically.  There is no reason to force the 301 redirect.  It will just happen based on bingbot visting your site, and updating their records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are instructions on how to tell Bing you have moved site: [Bing Site Move tool](http://www.bing.com/webmaster/help/how-to-use-the-site-move-tool-bb8f5112)

Basically:

> The **Site Move** tool, located under **Diagnostics & Tools** can be used to tell Bing that you have moved and permanently redirected your site (or a section of your site) to a new location. Although permanently redirecting your URLs using 301 redirects is sufficient for Bing to understand that you want the new URLs to be indexed instead of the old ones and this normally happens automatically, the **Site Move** tool can help expedite this process.

Comment: it's not there anymore, can't find it :(